# Android 11 update broke my File writing code

Tags: android, android-file, android-11

I've used this snippet before to **write a simple text file** with a name and a body:

```
public static File writeTextFile(String sFileName, String sBody) throws IOException {
        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), FOLDER_NAME);

    if (!root.exists()) {
        logFile("Not yet created, creating right now: " + root.getPath());
        root.mkdirs();

        logFile("Creation was successful? " + (root.exists() ? "Yes." : "No."));

    } else {
        logFile("Path exists: " + root.getPath());
    }

  
    File       measurementFile = new File(root, sFileName);
    FileWriter writer  = new FileWriter(measurementFile);
    writer.append(sBody);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

    return measurementFile;

}
```

It is working well **except for Android 11** which I just realized today after testing it on a OnePlus N10 which runs Android 11.

---

The problem is **I don't get any described error message just a simple exception** and I can't seem to find a way to go on after this problem has occurred.

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/example_myapp/content_file_to_upload_1635424827184: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492)
     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:236)
     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:186)
     at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:90)
     at com.myapp.example.util.FileUtil.writeTextFile(FileUtil.java:39)
     at com.myapp.example.services.ConnectionServiceForDownloadData$1.onCharacteristicChanged(ConnectionServiceForDownloadData.java:265)
     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt$1$8.run(BluetoothGatt.java:478)
     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt.runOrQueueCallback(BluetoothGatt.java:780)
     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt.access$200(BluetoothGatt.java:41)
     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt$1.onNotify(BluetoothGatt.java:472)
     at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGattCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothGattCallback.java:306)
     at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1170)
     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1134)
 Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
     at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:254)
     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7924)
     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:478)
    ... 12 more
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Um, [scoped storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage) has been a thing for over two years. You cannot create directories off of the external storage root, and you cannot write files in arbitrary locations. Either write to a location that you can write to (any `File`-returning method on `Context`, like `getExternalFilesDir()`), or use the Storage Access Framework to let the user choose where on the user's device (or the user's cloud storage) that the user wants you to write the user's text.

Comment: `root.mkdirs();

        logFile("Creation was successful? " + (root.exists() ? "Yes." : "No."));
` If 'No' you should not continue trying to create a file in a directory that not exists.

Comment: @CommonsWare Um

Comment: If your comment is with respect to the accepted answer, that's another place you can write (as with `DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS`). Note that other apps may not be able to work with the files that you create in those locations, unless that app uses the Storage Access Framework to let the user choose the files that you create. But, the point from my original comment still holds: you cannot create directories off of the external storage root, and you cannot write files in arbitrary locations.

Comment: @CommonsWare Didn't read

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> > File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), FOLDER_NAME);

Change to:

```
File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), FOLDER_NAME);
```

Comment: How can this be a solution since getExternalStoragePublicDirectory is deprecated in Android 10?

Comment: It is not anymore @MPaulo.

Comment: You're right. Strange, but true. Thanks.

Comment: DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS is older. With DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS, better test the version:

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {  }

Comment: @MPaulo, Why? Anything to download? This is just for saving to some files. Further the Download directory cannot be choosen anymore with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.

Comment: Just because there's no DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS below KITKAT

Comment: @MPaulo, ok but below KitKat there is no Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() call possible too. And one can create its own directories.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to your manifest.

Or change it to comply to Android 11's new scoped storage system.
See https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage